# Why str is called string slice, if &str is an actual string slice?

Tags: rust

Why `str` is called ***string slice***, if `&str` is an actual string slice?

Comment: Because it says so right in the docs: https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.str.html

Comment: You can call both string slices. The Rust terminology police won't come after you. Same way people call `dyn Trait`, `&dyn Trait`, and `Box<dyn Trait>` *"trait objects"*.

Comment: Another way of looking at it is that `&str` is a _string slice **reference**_, which is also known as "string slice" for short.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Going by the documentation:

- `str` is a "string slice" ([primitive type `str`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.str.html))
- `[T]` is a "slice" ([primitive type `slice`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html#method.new_uninit_slice_in))
- `dyn Trait` is a "trait object" ([keyword `dyn`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/keyword.dyn.html))

However, because they are [dynamically sized types](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/dynamically-sized-types.html), you often don't see them in this basic form alone. You'll most often see them used with some form of indirection, be it reference, `Box`, `Arc` or "smart pointer" type. So strictly speaking, a `&str` is a *"reference to string slice"*.

But the *"reference to-"* prefix is not particularly helpful in most contexts and is very wordy. So most will colloquially refer to `&str` as a *"string slice"* unless more precise terminology is warranted. If someone mentions a *"slice"*, you know they're referring to a *"dynamically-sized view into a contiguous sequence"*; the exact construction of is not important to its meaning.

Comment: [Here's a fairly recent issue that suggests making the naming more uniform](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/101353).

Comment: @kmdreko So `str` is a data structure that consists of a pointer to a memory chunk and a number of bytes and `&str` is a pointer to this data structure. Right?

Comment: @ЕвгенийПавлов no, `str` is the region of memory (that holds utf8 encoded bytes), `&str` is a reference to that region of memory (a.k.a. a pointer and length)

Comment: @kmdreko But that's the essence of the question. Why do rust programmers call 'str' a slice if it's actually a **value**? Documentation must explicitly state that 'str' is a value.

Comment: @ЕвгенийПавлов I'm not sure I understand what you mean by "value". An instance of type `str` has a value just as much as an instance of type `&str` has a value.

Comment: @kmdreko Well in C, C++, Java, C#, there is a notion of **value types** (actual raw data) and **reference types** (a pointer). For a programmer with prior experience Rust terminology is very confusing. Moreover if `str` is a region of memory, then why do you call it a _slice_? In everyday language we call _slice_ a part of something. But `str` is a region of memory that contain **whole** utf8 string, not a **part** of it.

Comment: @ЕвгенийПавлов a `str` doesn't have to be the whole string, it can be just a part of it. Comparing to other languages won't really help you understand `str`, like C++ has [`std::span`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/span) but that's equivalent to `&str`, not `str`. I don't know if any other languages has a distinction between the pointer-and-length type and the type representing the data being referenced. Even in Rust, `str` is an awkward type since it doesn't have a fixed size in memory, but it is useful to convey ownership (`&str` vs `Box<str>`)